# MatPlotLib Text Labels for Points on Polygon Blocked

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using MatPlotLib in Python and Poly3DCollection, I plotted 20 triangles to make a shape.

I want to label all the faces of the shape to make it easier to see how they relate to eachother, but I'm having problems when the label is facing me.

It doesn't show up unless it's blocked, or if the shape is blocked it's transparent. I think it's happening because the Polygon shapes are covering the labels?

How can I make the label take priority over the polygon shapes?

I've spent a while searching but can't find anything.

[image: solid]
[image: transparent]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you try using the `zorder` keyword? Se [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37246941/2454357) for an example.