# in matplotlib.pyplot, axvline cannot show after imshow(img)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('xxx.png')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0., 0.92, 0.1, 0.08])

ax1.imshow(img)

ax1.axvline(0.5, 0, 1, color='gray')

plt.show()
```

Running this code shows the img in the axes area.
However, the vline does not show up.

If I remove the line: `ax1.imshow(img)` and run again I do see the vline.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look how [zorder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37246941/2454357) works.

Comment: Also, your line will be very thin so might be hard to actually see it. Try increasing `linewidth` in `axvline`.

Answer (score 1):

Your line is probably being drawn over on the left hand y-axis. The `x` coordinate of `ax.axvline` is in data coordinates. The x-axis limits from the `ax.imshow` will be the number of pixels in the x-direction of the image. So, an `x` coordinate of 0.5 will be in the centre of the left-most pixel of the `imshow`.

Try increasing the `x` coordinate of the axvline to a bigger number, and you will probably see it.

From the [`axvline` docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-axvline):

> ```
> x : scalar, optional, default: 0
>
>     x position in data coordinates of the vertical line.
> ```

Consider this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.imshow(img)

ax.axvline(0.5, 0, 1, color='blue')
ax.axvline(200, 0, 1, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Note the blue line right against the left hand y-axis.

[image]