# Selecting interior nodes of an arbitrary 3D shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a point set in 3D and i want to pick the points that are inside the 3D shape enclosing by the boundary given as

```
ro(phi) = sqrt(cos(2*phi)+sqrt(1.4-(sin(2*phi))**2))

X = ro(phi) * cos(phi)
Y = ro(phi) * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
Z = ro(phi) * cos(theta) * sin(phi)

0 <= theta <= 2pi
0 <= phi <= pi
```

[image]

Is there a way of doing this in python environment?
I would  appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768031/plotting-points-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere-in-pythons-matplotlib

Comment: @CSMaverick: I read that post it is about the points on the sphere whereas I'm looking for the interior nodes of irregular shapes.

Comment: Along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750618/whats-an-efficient-way-to-find-if-a-point-lies-in-the-convex-hull-of-a-point-cl), maybe?

Comment: what happens if the shape is not convex?